# How can I add a textbox that searches all ToolStripMenuItem and only displays the ones that match?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a personal productivity tool I created to help automate as many tasks that I complete regularly as possible. It's visually represented by a NotifyIcon that displays the options in a ToolStrip when right-clicked.

Here is a screenshot of the tool. I'll put the TextBox at the bottom and it will be given focus on right-clicking the NotifyIcon: 
[https://i.imgur.com/s95vLJW.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9mPM.png)

I would like to add a TextBox that lists all ToolStripMenuItems with "text" values that match the text typed into the box, updating with every button press (think of the Windows start menu - much like that).

Unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve this and can't find the right terms to use to find relevant search results, so I have no code to show.

If there isn't any completed code available, I'd appreciate it if you could at least give me some search terms to help me find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .AutoComplete methods of the TextBox.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ToolStripItems As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    ToolStripItems.AddRange(New String() {"Copy ID", "Copy Facebook", "Copy Twitter"})
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ToolStripItems
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End Sub
```